RepositoryItemComboBox on Unbounded Data Column get blank when a value is selected
I have a RepositoryItemComboBox set as an editor of an unbounded data column. It has the list of all items that I would like to add, Item , Item 2, 'Item 3 and it can drop-down correctly.  The issue: it always shows show blank even if I already selected an item from the list.
I believe I need to handle the CustomUnboundColumnData event, however, I cannot cast myRepositoryItemComboBox to get its selected item.
